# Encrypting db password in application.conf

Tags: playframework

Play framework [I'm using v1.2.3] does not support db password encryption stored in the application.conf. This is stored as a plain-text file. DBPlugin reads this property and creates a Connection pool.

The requirement is to encrypt this password - for e.g. using [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/). Some enterprises enforce this as a security measure.

Has anybody tried doing something like this?

Since DBPlugin loads on ApplicationStart, there is no way to hack it. That leaves to write a custom plugin and [onConfigurationRead](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.3/play/PlayPlugin.html#onConfigurationRead%28%29) set a new value for the db.password of application.conf property.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Interesting question, you could also post this on the [Play Google group](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework) to ensure you get maximum coverage.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally I fixed this by writing a Play Plugin. Writing a Play plugin is also very easy.
Here is the sample code:

```
package plugin;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.jasypt.util.text.StrongTextEncryptor;

import play.Play;
import play.PlayPlugin;

public class DBPasswordInject extends PlayPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationRead() {
        StrongTextEncryptor strongTextEncryptor = new StrongTextEncryptor();
        strongTextEncryptor.setPassword("$Look##$2");// this password has been used to encrypt

        String encryptedPassword = Play.configuration.getProperty("db.pass");
        String decrypted = strongTextEncryptor.decrypt(encryptedPassword);
        Play.configuration.setProperty("db.pass", decrypted); //override

        super.onConfigurationRead();
    }

}
```

The only downside is that I was not able to use **org.jasypt.util.password.StrongPasswordEncryptor** - because there is no decrypt method.

Comment: If you use the org.jasypt.encryption.StringEncryptor class you have access to both encrypt and decrypt

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem is which password should be used to encrypt the password? If you use a default password it's not safe too. If you put it into the configuration file you have a recursive problem. The only solution I see is to use your own plugin where the password is stored and change the values in the application properties. Then the password can be stored crytped with no problems. At least in Play1.x.

Comment: jasypt allows the encryption password to be looked up at runtime from the system env or java properties. That password never needs be checked into source control systems or have the circular problem you highlighted.

Comment: Please never put a password into the command line. If you use another propertyfile you could use the play-functionality directly.