# Encrypting db password in application.conf for Play 2.0/anorm

Tags: database, scala, encryption, playframework, playframework-2.0

I don't want to put unencrypted passwords in the application config file.

This question: [Encrypting db password in application.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200404/encrypting-db-password-in-application-conf) has a great solution for the problem but it works only for Play 1.

Does anybody know a solution that works for Play 2.0? I am using anorm in Scala version of Play 2.0.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to discussion with Raffaele and following my own investigation of the code, it seems that Play 2.0 does not allow you to encrypt DB passwords.

If I missed something please let me know.

**EDIT**: One can work around the problem by using custom database driver in the following manner:

```
// Just redirect everything to the delegate
class DelegatingDriver(delegate: Driver) extends Driver
{
  def connect(url: String, info: Properties) = delegate.connect(url, info)
  def acceptsURL(url: String) = delegate.acceptsURL(url)
  def getPropertyInfo(url: String, info: Properties) = delegate.getPropertyInfo(url, info)
  def getMajorVersion = delegate.getMajorVersion
  def getMinorVersion = delegate.getMinorVersion
  def jdbcCompliant() = delegate.jdbcCompliant()
}

// Replace password in properties with the decrypted one
class MyDecryptingDriver extends DelegatingDriver(Class.forName("<my.original.Driver>").newInstance().asInstanceOf[Driver])
{
  override def connect(url: String, info: Properties)= {
    // copy Properties
    val overriddenProperties= clone(info)   
    // override password property with the decrypted value
    Option(info.getProperty("password")).foreach(value => overriddenProperties.setProperty("password", decryptPassword(value)))
    super.connect(url, overriddenProperties)
  }

  def clone(orig: Properties)= {
    val result= new Properties()
    orig.propertyNames().map(_.asInstanceOf[String]).foreach(pName => result.setProperty(pName, orig.getProperty(pName)))
    result
  }

  def decryptPassword(encrypted: String)= ...
}
```

then you replace application.conf/db..driver by my.com.MyDecrypting driver. Not perfect but works for me...

Answer (score 3):

All efforts are pointless. When we put hashed password in a database is because humans can retain passwords in their brains, and **their brains are not readable**. It's called *asymmetric* encryption.

The thing your are talking about is only possible with *symmetric* encryption: the program has the key at runtime, and uses this key to decrypt the db password. But what's the point in storing the db password encrypted with a key, and still having this key publicly available? (This is true for both java sources and compiled classes). A chain is only as strong as its weakest link.

When a machine has to connect to a db, it needs a password: we store this password in plain text because the program must use it as is, and **no human input is required**. All we can do to enforce security is to restrict the access to this plain text file, eventually protecting it with a password stored only in the admin's mind (BTW, more likely the admin will keep all of its passwords in a database, maybe with a master password). Note that things don't change if you use the mentioned Play plugin.

The only other thing that comes to my mind is a Play app which only connects to the db when the admin inputs the db password (but really this is only a thinking exercise)

Comment: OK, so going with your thinking exercise, how would I make Play use the password input by the Admin from the console?

Comment: 1. Don't configure the default datasource
2. Write a Controller to get the password and use this password to start a new EBean server
3. Extend [`play.db.ebean.Model`](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/db/ebean/Model.java) or [`play.db.ebean.EbeanPlugin`](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/db/ebean/EbeanPlugin.java) to use this server (or really find any other way, I can't help you with this)

Comment: Actually, it seems that you don't need to extend anything. Ebean has the concept of a *default server*. See [this doc](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/config/ServerConfig.html#setDefaultServer(boolean))

Comment: Thanks for trying but I am not using Ebeans, I was actually looking for anorm solution (like the one in the linked question)

Comment: It's not very different, I think. Sql() uses an implicit Connection, so one simply needs to get one with the admin-provided password

Comment: Thanks. The way I understand your answer is that Play doesn't have the requested functionality and I need to create the connection myself. Please let me know if I got it wrong.

Comment: Re: "All efforts are pointless...": I disagree. There are different levels of protection and different attacks you are protecting from. In this case, I am protecting from enticing people to copy and use my cleartext password. I understand that symmetric encryption doesn't give you protection from a determined uber-hacker but then, what does? By the same logic, you shouldn't need front door lock in a house because a thief can easily break through a window.
Security is what you make it and good tools should be flexible enough to support different use cases. Play 2.0 failed the test here.

Comment: You are certainly entitled to your opinion, but please notice these two things: 1. Every framework on earth store the password in some plain text file: can they all be wrong and not caring security enough? 2. What are we protecting here, exactly? A DB password by itself is not that useful: you can tell me what your password is, and still I won't be able to connect to your db and steal/manipulate your data. The sensitive information is that stored **inside the db**, and it's a sysadmin's role to keep the data secure. There's no much a programmer can do that a bad sysadmin could not disrupt

Comment: have the admin set up an env var and then use: my.key = ${?MY_KEY_ENV}

"Here, the override field my.key = ${?MY_KEY_ENV} simply vanishes if there’s no value for MY_KEY_ENV, but if you set an environment variable MY_KEY_ENV for example, it would be used." -- http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.x/ProductionConfiguration

Comment: "But what's the point in storing the db password encrypted with a key, and still having this key publicly available"

Because you can keep the key less available than your source code. Source code/text config lives in several places: developer machines, code repos as well as the production server. If your encryption key is only available at runtime on the production server the information is significantly more secure.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a bit late but there's not newer discussions about this problema. I want to share the actual solution (Play v.2.5.X), as suggested in [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Advanced:-Extending-the-GuiceApplicationLoader), is now possible to override the `GuiceApplicationLoader` to configure the `GuiceApplicationBuilder` to process someway the initial configs.

In a new class `modules/ApplicationLoaderConfig.scala`:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter

import play.api.inject.guice._
import play.api.{ApplicationLoader, Configuration}

class ApplicationLoaderConfig extends GuiceApplicationLoader() {

  override def builder(context: ApplicationLoader.Context): GuiceApplicationBuilder = {

    // Decrypt secrets
    val decryptedConfig = context.initialConfiguration ++
      Configuration("config.to.descrypt.1" -> decryptDES(context.initialConfiguration.getString("config.to.descrypt.1").get)) ++
      Configuration("config.to.descrypt.2" -> decryptDES(context.initialConfiguration.getString("config.to.descrypt.2").get))

    initialBuilder
      .in(context.environment)
      .loadConfig(decryptedConfig)
      .overrides(overrides(context): _*)
  }

  private def decryptDES(secret: String): String = {
    val key = "12345678"
    val skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "DES")

    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding")
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec)

    new String(cipher.doFinal(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(secret)))
  }
}
```

Also add to `application.config`:

```
play.application.loader = "modules.ApplicationLoaderConfig"
```

Comment: Thanks for following up @federico-baron! I will use this next time I do a Play app.

Comment: I think a better link would be this one https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Advanced:-Extending-the-GuiceApplicationLoader :)