# How to configure database access during runtime with anorm?

Tags: sql, database, playframework, anorm

Currently anorm uses the parameters specified in *application.config* file of Play to access to a database (user, password, url).

In my case, I need to specify the connection url during the runtime.

Is there a pretty trick to do this? How can I do this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to implement a delegate to the anorm driver? See this question for reference: [Encrypting db password in application.conf for Play 2.0/anorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656712/encrypting-db-password-in-application-conf-for-play-2-0-anorm)