# Protect Play framework applications MySQL password and app secret within Amazon Linux EC2

Tags: linux, security, amazon-web-services, playframework, privileges

I have setup a Amazon linux EC2 that I use to host a Play Framework application, the app uses a local mysql database to store sensitive information (usernames and passwords). If somehow someone managed to gain access to the server how can I protect the sensitive information stored in the database?

I have set up MySQL to have a strong password, however the password needs to be stored in the application's configuration file, all an attacker has to do is look in the applications code/configuration file, or just, i.e. grep -r db.default.password

This configuration file also stores the app secret key which is used for encrypting data within the database, so from this single file an attacker could gain access to my data and then decrypt it.

How can I secure these details?

Comment: I feel like one solution would be to place the application in a folder that requires sudo privileges to access, then add then require a password to use sudo. Linux is not one of my strongest suits, but does that seem like a legitimate solution?

Comment: The answer to this question looks like your best option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200404/encrypting-db-password-in-application-conf

Comment: thanks for posting that, I think this may be a potential solution, however I feel that it would also be beneficial to protect the source code and other settings in the configureation file using something along the lines of what I described above

Comment: do you know if what I described is possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Search is your friend: http://superuser.com/questions/783939/amazon-ec2-prompt-password-when-sudo/783948

Comment: haha yes, thankyou, however now that I have a password on root, what is my next step? where do I place the application so that the ec2-user cannot access it without su?

Comment: In any directory that is owned by root and has permissions that restrict other users from accessing it. Or just set those permissions directly on the file. Again, search is your friend: https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions

Comment: me and search are #veryGoodFriends