# How to handle encrypting database password in Play Framework 2.6 application.conf ?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3

I have a Play Java application and in conf/application.conf file , I don't want to put database.password property in plain text. I tried encrypting password as mentioned in this post. ([Encrypting db password in application.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200404/encrypting-db-password-in-application-conf)) but play 2.6 errors out saying cannot find symbol PlayPlugin.

Any recommendation on how to encrypt password in play confs ?